# How to stop validation invocation in case of deserialization exception in asp.net core webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using FluentValidation.AspNetCore to validate my viewmodel. I have filter with a pair of datetime? properties inside.
 When i send invalid datetime (2019-17-10T00:00:00) I get 2 validation messages instead of 1(The first one is deserialization error and the second one is from fluent validation). Does anybody know how to stop validation invocation in case of deserialization exception.

My startup config

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers(o =>
        {
            o.ModelValidatorProviders.Clear();
        }).AddFluentValidation(cfg => cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());  
    }
```

My controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
{
    private static List<Employee> _employees = new List<Employee> { new Employee { FirstName = "Sarah", LastName = "Connor", Birthday = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-40) } };


    [HttpGet]
    public Task<List<Employee>> GetAsync([FromQuery] EmployeeFilter filter)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_employees);
    }
}
```

my models

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeFilter
{
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
}
```

Validators

```
public class EmployeeValidator : AbstractValidator<EmployeeFilter>
{
    public EmployeeValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.DateFrom).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.DateTo).NotNull();
    }
}
```

I expect to get just only deserialization exception

```
"DateTo": [
        "The value '2019-17-10T00:00:00' is not valid for DateTo.",
    ]
```

But actual was:

```
"DateTo": [
        "The value '2019-17-10T00:00:00' is not valid for DateTo.",
        "'Date To' must not be empty."
    ]
```

So after deserialization DateTo is null and fluent validation adds one additional message.
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny3Jr.png)

Comment: 1. Why do declare a type of `DateTime?` for `DateTo` and then add rule that requires it to be `NotNull`? Why not use `DateTime` directly? 2. If you want to skip validations early,  add a method: `protected override bool PreValidate(ValidationContext<EmployeeFilter> context, ValidationResult result) {
return !(context.InstanceToValidate?.DateFrom == null || context.InstanceToValidate?.DateTo == null  ); }`

Comment: 1. Well. Filter can contains optional and required arguments. DateFrom and DateTo are conditional here. So they are nullable. We can add other required parameters like EmployeeType for ex 2.If we use datetime they will be always required and client always has to define them.  Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work for me.